# Tomcat Executor MBean

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jmx

I am using an embedded version of Tomcat 7.0.42. Using java executor with either of the connectors i.e. BIO/NIO.

However while monitoring the server via JMX, I see the mbean attributes,

```
currentThreadCount

currentThreadsBusy
```

always showing the value "-1".

The only one that shows the appropriate dynamic value is connection count, which seems to match the count of the client threads that I initiate.

Any idea how to get currentThreadCount and currentThreadsBusy to show the right values?

Thanks

Comment: Is this the same issue? However, the thread says it's not applicable for Tomcat 7.x. I see you are also using executor. http://serverfault.com/questions/242368/tomcat-jmx-monitoring-busy-threads

Comment: Yes, the thread seems to raise the same issue. And i am seeing similar behavior in Tomcat 7.x as well with an executor.